# Turn a URL into content preview

Tags: ajax, comments, urls

Is it possible when you paste a URL into comments to transform it to a content preview like Facebook does?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. However, you would need to develop that functionality either in a plugin or adding it to the functions.php file of the active wordpress theme. Are you asking for a functioning example or someone to code it for you?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. I don't want someone to do it for me, that is innaproppriate. A functioning example could do the job for me. I should mention that i use wpDiscuz comment system in my website and not WordPress's default commenting system.

Comment: It is definitely doable, though I don't know of any existing such functionality. I know I can code it, however It will depend on whether or not  your current commenting system allows to post HTML objects directly. It can be done by Ajax/jQuery